# Xml or text Declaration not starting With Entity in android

Tags: android, xml

Hi i am very new for android and in my app i have created ratingbar_drawable.xml file in my Drawable Folder ok that's fine

and i have added this xml file in style's folder and when i run my app i am getting Errors like "Xml or text Declaration not starting With Entity" and i am sure getting this exception by means of ratingbar_drawable.xml

please help me what is the problem here

### ratingbar_drawable.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

### styles.xml:-

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />



 <style name="ratingBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">

        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_drawable</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

to

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

in your ***ratingbar_drawable.xml***

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving only one of this lines on your **ratingbar_drawable.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```